# is it possible to speed up writing numbers in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering, in cases when you have to write big numbers such as 50.000.000.000, is it possible to write something like.. BILLION(50) or any shortcut?

Comment: Do you want BILLION(50) as an output from a query, or do you want something where you don't have to type as many zeros when composing a query?

Comment: I'm looking for the 2nd option

Comment: In what way is jQuery - a JavaScript library mostly for DOM manipulation, related to databases?

Comment: Can you show an example case when you want to use such numbers?

Comment: As a separate question - how have you identified that big numbers are slow to write to a database?

Comment: @VLAZ: By observing how long it takes to type them out.  OP's typing speed is probably not very good, although it's hard to imagine spending a lot of effort tapping the zero key ten times.

Comment: Are you writing the numbers in a query? Are you importing it from another file where you type it? How are you planning to send it into the database? Import? Write in a db client? Write INSERT QUERIES?

Comment: @nazim: Look at the first and second comments, above.

Comment: @Robert Harvey... Then he should accept ysth answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use 5e10 (meaning 5 x 10<sup>10</sup>).  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/number-literals.html

But numbers expressed in scientific notation like that are interpreted as floating point constants, with a more limited precision, and calculations using them will continue to use floating point.  For example:

```
select 5e16-1, 50000000000000000-1;
```

returns

| 5e16 | 49999999999999999 |
| --- | --- |

Comment: could you elaborate or use an example query=

Comment: `UPDATE someTable SET someField = 5e10`

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4f2e1990aec517c52a02d61d7a4dff6e

Comment: It's called Scientific Notation.  You can read more about it [here](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=376253#:~:text=MySQL%20understands%20scientific%20notation.,legal%20numbers%20in%20scientific%20notation.).

Comment: @DanielRoca you need to come up with the example query; I could only guess at what you are hoping to do.